# Where/How does fetchmail store which mail it has seen?

Tags: email, migration, fetchmail

I use fetchmail to fetch mail from a remote POP3 server and deliver it to my local mail server. Now I want to migrate fetchmail from one server to another. But where/how does fetchmail store/know which mails it has already seen? I don't want to end up with duplicates in my inbox after migration. My fetchmail configuration does not delete seen mail, so there are still mails available on the remote server that were already processed by fetchmail on the old server instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fetchmail by default stores ids of fetched emails in `.fetchids` file (`~/.fetchids`).
See `--idfile` in [`man fetchmail`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fetchmail&manpath=SuSE%20Linux/i386%2011.3)

Comment: Using fetchmail as a service, I could not find a matching .fetchid file. It seems at least in this case that fetchmail just looks at read/unread status of mail on server. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67296/82430 as source.

Comment: @AndreasReiff fetchmail **bydefault* deletes fetched POP3 message, In case of fetchamil service you can change it  via options in `/etc/fetchmairc' .   1) `keep` option per mailbox. 2) `idfile` global option to specify fetchid file location

Comment: Thanks @AnFi . In my case, it wasn't normal operation: the message was too large and did not get fetched, just an error message in the inbox. After increasing the limit, it did not get downloaded again. (Might have been me checking directly in the mailbox though and marking the mail as read.. not 100%ly sure.) It got downloaded after marking it as unread again.

Comment: how do you specify where mail is stored?

Comment: @NicholasSaunders see `--smtphost` xor `--mda` in `man fetchmail`.  If you want more detailed recipe then as new question with info **WHERE** messages should be deliver in your case.